# css layout in php gallery

Tags: css, html, layout, gallery

I've been working on a gallery made in php. Some time ago, I made the layout using tables. It worked out super. Now, using tables for layouts is not recommended and sort of "deprecated" (I don't understand why, if someone could explain this to me, thank you). So, I'm trying to change the layout from tables to divs and I'm having a lot of problems (can someone recommend a good reference to how to make a good layout using css?). So far I managed this: http://jsfiddle.net/hochvater/4DbUU/ . MY FIRST QUESTION is this: how do I make the #panel_poze div to show up in the top of the container div, glued to the #panel_albume (as it is now)? I don't understand why #panel_albume is lined with the 3rd div contained by the div it is glued to (#panel_albume). My second question would be this: can't I just put the big table (you can imagine easily how it looks by the structure of the divs) into a container div and sort of leave it as it was...would this still be considered "deprecated" or not recommended?

THE CSS CODE:

```
    body {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
@font-face {
    font-family:"john_handy";
    src: url("john_handy.eot");
    src: local("¢"), url("john_handy.woff") format("woff"), url("john_handy.TTF") format("opentype"), url("john_handy.svg#john_handy") format("svg");
}
@font-face {
    font-family:"bradley_hand";
    src: url("bradley_hand.eot");
    src: local("¢"), url("bradley_hand.woff") format("woff"), url("bradley_hand.TTF") format("opentype"), url("bradley_hand.svg#bradley_hand") format("svg");
}
a:link {
    color:white;
}
/* unvisited link */
 a:visited {
    color:white;
}
/* visited link */
 a:hover {
    color:red;
}
/* mouse over link */
 a:active {
    color:blue;
}
/* selected link */
 .fonty {
    text-align:center;
    font: italic 30px john_handy, serif;
}
a.fonty {
    font-style: normal;
    font-size:20px;
}
#pp {
    margin: 15% auto;
    max-width:80%;
    min-width:850px;
    text-align: center;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
.sec {
    position: static;
    margin: 0% 4%;
    max-width: 20%;
    min-width: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.imageOff {
    border: 3px solid transparent;
    margin: auto;
}
.imageOn {
    border: 3px solid red;
    opacity: 0.7;
    filter: alpha(opacity=70);
    margin: auto;
}
.selected {
    padding: 2px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.submit {
    /*margin: 0;*/
    border: none;
    /*padding: 0;*/
    background: black;
    font:normal 20px john_handy, serif;
    color:white;
}
.subsel {
    color:red;
}
.submit:hover {
    color:red;
}
.poze_albume {
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 250px;
    width: 200px;
}
#panel_poze {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    width: 70%;
    min-width: 400px;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100px;
}
#panel_albume {
    border: 1px solid yellow;
    display:inline-block;
}
#container {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid white;
    min-width: 700px;
}
.album {
}
```

THE GALLERY CODE:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./zastyle.css" />
</head>

<body><!-- oncontextmenu="return false;"> -->

<h1 class="fonty">Portofolio</h1>

<?php 
if (!isset($_POST['restart']))
{
?>

<div id="pp">
    <div class="sec ">
    <form action="./galerie.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input class="imageOff" onmouseover="this.className='imageOn'" onmouseout="this.className='imageOff'" type="image" src="./studio/photoshoot.JPG" title="Studio Photography" alt="Studio Photography" />
        <input type="hidden" name="album" value="studio" />
        <input type="hidden" name="restart" value="1"/>
        <br />
        <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Studio Photography" />
    </form>
    </div>
    <div class="sec ">
    <form action="./galerie.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input class="imageOff" onmouseover="this.className='imageOn'" onmouseout="this.className='imageOff'" type="image" src="./outdoor_lifestyle/lifestyle.jpg" title="Outdoor and Lifestyle Photography" alt="Outdoor and Lifestyle Photography" />
        <input type="hidden" name="album" value="outdoor" />
        <input type="hidden" name="restart" value="1"/>
        <br />
        <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Outdoor and Lifestyle" />
    </form>
    </div>
    <div class="sec " >
    <form action="./galerie.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input class="imageOff" onmouseover="this.className='imageOn'" onmouseout="this.className='imageOff'" type="image" src="./landscapes/landscapes.jpg" title="Landscapes" alt="Landscapes" class="album" />
        <input type="hidden" name="album" value="landscapes" />
        <input type="hidden" name="restart" value="1" />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Landscapes" />
    </form>
    </div>
    </form>
</div>

<?php //require("za_menu.php"); ?>

<?php
}
if (isset($_POST['restart'])&&$_POST['restart']==1){
?>

<div id="container">
    <div id="panel_albume">
        <div class="poze_albume">
        <form action="./galerie.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input class="imageOff <?php
            if($_POST['album']=='studio') echo 'selected';
            ?>" onmouseover="this.className='imageOn'" onmouseout="this.className='imageOff <?php
            if($_POST['album']=='studio') echo 'selected';
            ?>'" type="image" src="./studio/photoshoot.JPG" title="Studio Photography" alt="Studio Photography" />
            <input type="hidden" name="album" value="studio" />
            <input type="hidden" name="restart" value="1" />
            <br />
            <input type="submit" class="submit <?php
            if($_POST['album']=='studio') echo 'subsel';
            ?>" value="Studio Photography" />
        </form>
        </div>
        <div  class="poze_albume">
        <form action="./galerie.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input class="imageOff <?php
            if($_POST['album']=='outdoor') echo 'selected';
            ?>" onmouseover="this.className='imageOn'" onmouseout="this.className='imageOff <?php
            if($_POST['album']=='outdoor') echo 'selected';
            ?>'" type="image" src="./outdoor_lifestyle/lifestyle.jpg" title="Outdoor and Lifestyle Photography" alt="Outdoor and Lifestyle Photography" />
            <input type="hidden" name="album" value="outdoor" />
            <input type="hidden" name="restart" value="1" />
            <br />
            <input type="submit" class="submit <?php
            if($_POST['album']=='outdoor') echo 'subsel';
            ?>" value="Outdoor and Lifestyle" />
        </form>
        </div>
        <div  class="poze_albume">
        <form action="./galerie.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input class="imageOff <?php
            if($_POST['album']=='landscapes') echo 'selected';
            ?>" onmouseover="this.className='imageOn'" onmouseout="this.className='imageOff <?php
            if($_POST['album']=='landscapes') echo 'selected';
            ?>'" type="image" src="./landscapes/landscapes.jpg" title="Landscapes" alt="Landscapes" class="album"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="album" value="landscapes" />
            <input type="hidden" name="restart" value="1" />
            <br />
            <input type="submit" class="submit <?php
            if($_POST['album']=='landscapes') echo 'subsel';
            ?>" value="Landscapes" />
        </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="panel_poze"></div>
</div>

<?php }
session_destroy();
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Thank you for your time invested in reading this and any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recomend you to take a look at a CSS grid system, such as [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/index.html) or [960.gs](http://960.gs/)

To answer your question about tables: the use of tables were ok before CSS. CSS will help you organize your content in much better and flexible ways. I suggest you take a look at [CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/) and the [W3 CSS tutorials](http://www.w3schools.com/css/) to make sure you understand how `<div>` works and how you can float them around. Also, HTML5 take the semantic meaning of the containers and will allow you to better represent the structure of your site. Take a look at [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) if you want to learn more or even get a initial template to work with.

Comment: Thanks...I'll try to do that, for the moment...but still, my first question wasn't answered :) Thanks a lot anyways...I'm gonna start reading now

Comment: @AngellumManaflow, your welcome! Your question is very specific and in a way it wouldn't help future references, so I prefer to guide you to learn a few nice things than vote down and flag (as recomened on StackOverflow). But it would be costly to debug such specific code here anyway. So have fun! :)

Comment: hmmm...nice 960.gs but I don't see the relevance of it in my case...CSS Tricks, I know it...probably I'll post the question there, too...Boilerplate looks interesting, too, but I also don't see the relevance to my problem...And w3schools...lets just say that I started web-programming with them :)

Comment: I see...well, I'm doing my best, as you can see I've done my research, but that's why I need the help of gurus who can show me directly where I make mistakes...thanks again :)

Comment: @AngellumManaflow, the point of all those grids and sites is to get a foundation for those who are not yet ok with working with CSS and to take out the need to worry much with positioning. Also, if you are used to work with tables, they will get you up and running faster. Although naturally the best path is to get to understand the weirdness of some CSS and rock :)

Comment: @AngellumManaflow thats the best way to learn online. failing and trying again. Feel free to contact me!

Comment: That's my point...rather that using already coded parts I'd rather learn how to code in the first place...I think it's easier to understand the "template" examples you've given me rather than working with them and not knowing how to get to code them...I hope you see my point... :)

Comment: @AngellumManaflow, I do see your point! As we don't know each other I don't know how much code you know nor if the above code was developed by you or pasted from somewhere else. But I must say I use those grids a lot when because they work great and get some work done in no time. Specially the HTML boilerplate and Twitter Bootstrap, I must say

Comment: No...the code posted above is written directly by me and it's not stolen or copy-pasted from somewhere else...that's why I told you I prefer to learn rather than use already coded parts/templates...

Comment: Read also the first reply I gave Michael.

Comment: @AngellumManaflow, Try floating one to the left and the other to the right. That's what I'd do when working inside a container.

Comment: I figured it out! Sorry for wasting your time, guys! In the css code, the height of 100px of #panel_poze div was the problem...I changed that and it worked just fine! Look on the link to jsfiddle for the change!

Comment: yeah, I know that option, too...I'll try that now...not sure how it will work, but it's another way of soving this...of course, the min-width of the container should be also set if I want the floating to work correctly for the dynamic resize :D :P

Comment: it just needs a bit of scaling tinkering :P :D

Comment: and Michael did what you suggested

Comment: I'll try to update as my changes and while I make tests...thank you for your replies and ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Roping off of Andre's answer above.  A good way to practice is to simply make a website which has very basic CSS properties, but multiple different formats of the divs, so that you can understand how the boxes interact.

One such project that I did way back when was to simple make a site with a header, a horizontal navigation, then several content blocks that were full-width, 50% - 50% dual columns, 25% - 50% - 25% triple column, 33% - 33% - 33% triple, and 25%-25%-25%-25% quad columns, then a footer.

Something you should definitely be looking into is responsive layout so you can make your gallery mobile friendly.

**Edit:**

Is this what you were meaning as far what you want it to look like?

http://jsfiddle.net/4DbUU/1/

I changed these rules:

```
#panel_poze {
border: 1px solid blue;
width: 70%;
min-width: 400px;
height: 100px;
float: left;
}

#panel_albume {
border: 1px solid yellow;
    float: left;
}

#container {
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
border: 1px solid white;
min-width: 700px;
clear: both;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

I deleted your `display: inline-block;` and added `float: left;` to both children.  Then I told the container to set `overflow:hidden;` and to `clear:both;` (left and right floats)

**Edit 2:**

For clarity requested by the OP...

In lamens terms, when using `float:left` or `float:right` on an element, in a way picks that element up off the page and allows it to "float" which ever direction you tell it to.  It performs this float with complete disregard to elements that are nearby which are not floated.  Elements that are nearby then start to wrap around the floated element.  This is sometimes desirable, for example floating an image left or right and allowing the text to wrap around the image.  In some cases however you don't want other elements to wrap around the ones you have floated.  In those cases you use the `clear` command to tell the next closest element to not wrap around floated elements.  See these two examples:

http://jsfiddle.net/GL4Pn/2/

In the above example, no clear is present.  Notice the text in the yellow `.footer` div is coming up between the two floated elements.

http://jsfiddle.net/GL4Pn/3/

In this example I have added `clear: left;` to `.footer` (the yellow div).  Notice it is no longer wrapping up into the tiny space between divs, but it is still wrapping aroudn the element to the right.

http://jsfiddle.net/GL4Pn/4/

Here I have switched it to `clear: right;` notice it is no longer wrapping up to the left div or in the space between divs anymore.  It is nested neatly beneath the right div.  This is because the right div is the longest div.  If I was to increase the height of the left div to be longer than the right div...

...Like here: http://jsfiddle.net/GL4Pn/5/

Notice now the div wraps up to the right, but not between the divs.  Now.. If I change the code to `clear: both;`...

http://jsfiddle.net/GL4Pn/6/

Notice it is back to how it was with `clear:right` when the right div was longest.  And if I change the left div to be shorter than the right and keep `clear:both` in place...

http://jsfiddle.net/GL4Pn/7/

The same result as before...

It is important to note that elements will only wrap floats if they are the very next element in the code.  If I go back to the first example with no clear, but add an extra div beneath footer, you'll see that it does not misbehave as the .footer div has already take the available space.

http://jsfiddle.net/GL4Pn/8/

Comment: Thanks for your reply, that's true, but for the moment I strictly need someone to explain me what can I do in css to make that damn section where the pictures contained in an album should be shown to be stretched the whole container div and not just half of it...if you look at the jsfiddle link, you'll see that it stays somewhere near the 3rd div contained by it's "brother" div...and I don't understand why isn't it as big in height as it's brother div...they're both in the same container...aren't they?

Comment: I want to do things step-by-step, after I finish what I want to do, I'll worry about making it look friendlier for mobile platforms, etc...

Comment: I figured it out! Sorry for wasting your time, guys! In the css code, the height of 100px of #panel_poze div was the problem...I changed that and it worked just fine! Look on the link to jsfiddle for the change!

Comment: I've written in caps to display my excitement :D

Comment: That was going to be my next comment, if the height needs to be fluid you needed to delete the height attribute on the style rule, which it seems you have figured out already.  Good luck!

Comment: Can you help me with something? Such that I will not ask stupid questions again or get confused...why did you put the clear: both? I don't understand the logic...can you please explain to me? Thank you.

Comment: @AngellumManaflow I have edited the original post with an explanation and examples of clear.  This will help you visually understand what is going on.